# Oracle SQL Update on Inner Join

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, dst

Stuck on something I a bit simpler this morning.

I have the following issue with readings and Daylight savings times going a bit mad.

I need to set OLD = NEW in the following.

```
select d.t0100 as tab1,
       t.t2400 as tab2
    from reportro.non_dst_readings d
        inner join reportro.dst_readings t
            on d.cust = t.cust
            and to_date(d.readdate_ndst, 'dd-mmm-yy') 
                 = (to_date(t.readdate, 'dd-mmm-yy') -1);
```

^^ But the above select isn't working, much less the update.

I was going to try to update them by:

```
update (
select d.t0100 as tab1,
       t.t2400 as tab2
    from report.non_dst_readings d
        inner join report.dst_readings t
            on d.cust = t.cust
            on to_date(d.readdate_ndst, 'dd-mmm-yy') 
                 = (to_date(t.readdate, 'dd-mmm-yy') -1)
        )
 set old = new;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks again, I'd be so lost without StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**NEW**](http://psoug.org/definition/NEW.htm) is a keyword in Oracle , use something else as identifier.
Also correct the ON syntax , a JOIN can have only one ON clause

```
update (
select d.t0100 as oldVal ,
       t.t2400 as newVaL
    from report.non_dst_readings d
        inner join report.dst_readings t
            on d.cust = t.cust
            WHERE to_date(d.readdate_ndst, 'dd-mm-yyyy') 
                 = (to_date(t.readdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') -1)
        )
 set oldVal = newVaL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm still getting "ORA-01821: date format not recognized", do you think it's an issue with the where clause, taking a day away on the fly?

Comment: @BenCoughlan the correct format is dd-mm-yyyy  and not dd-mmm-yy.check edited answet

Comment: AAAH, was using Caps, @m hasan thank you so so much! :D